# VSO BUILD run tests on Azure Resource Group

Tags: alm, azure-resource-manager, azure-devops

We're currently implementing an automated build process using Visual Studio Team Services Build.
The plan is to run tests on Azure VM's as part of a daily build. So far we've set up a build definition with an "Azure Resource Group Deployment"-step. This works fine, and a resource group template is deployed and the VM's in this template is started.

Next step is to install the test agent on these servers. I've added the "Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment" task, but has not been able to configure it properly.
There is a dropdown with the title "Test Machine Group / Azure Resource Group", but it only lets me choose between test machine groups. I'm not able to select nor enter a resource group name.

How do I deploy the test agent to the VM's in my newly created Azure Resource Group?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the VM first to enable the winrm service (Required for test agent deploy step). Refer to this link for details: [Enable Remote Powershell Service](http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/).

And then go to VSTS Web Portal -> Test -> Machines, create a Machine group and add the Azure VM in it. Now you can select the new created machine group in "Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment" task for test agent deploy.

Comment: Thanks:) I'm not sure it addresses my issues completely.
The Azure Resource Group (including the VM's) is deployed as part of the build process. The article you link to requires manually setting up PowerShell for remote access. The process should be automated, so I cannot add a manual step between deploying the Resource Group and installing the test agent.
Also, when setting up the test deployment task, the title of the dropdown is "Test Machine Group / Azure Resource Group", so I would imagine that I was able to select a Resource Group directly without creating a machine group.

Comment: Hi @SørenSparsø You just need to enable winrm service for once. This is a prerequisites to run testing on remote machines as "Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment" use remote powershell to check/configure test agent. You have to enable it manually no matter which task you use. I cannot select Azure Resource Group from the dropdown list either :(, that's why I recommend you to use Test Machine Group.